# Should I use async or Task to handle a lot of concurrent operations?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I am writing a Windows Service that is going to process a lot of input files.

My question is whether I should use `async` and `await`, or if I should create a custom library using `Task` that could limit the number of concurrent threads.

I know for a fact that if I queue up 200 threads, it takes longer to complete everything than letting 10 run at a time (various fighting for resources, context switching in the CPU, etc, etc)

So my question is whether these new fangled features `async` and `await` are any more runtime resilient, or should I just write my own custom library??

Comment: I don't see you don't just use the TPL which has a lot of stuff for this already. If you're I/O based, you may well not even want 10 threads. You should look at TPL Dataflow as well, btw.

Comment: Just started looking into TPL Dataflow recently as well and it definitely seems like a good candidate for this task +1

Comment: thanks @JonSkeet.  I am not as super-awesome as you and probably a bit behind on the latest and greatest frameworks.  I will dig into TPL Dataflow :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing I/O-based operations, `async` and `await` are great. In a Win32 service, you don't have a `SynchronizationContext`, so all your continuations end up as tasks on the thread pool, which does a great job of load balancing. (Remember, `Task` != `Thread`; hundreds or even thousands of `Task`s are just fine).

If you're doing CPU-based operations, then I'd recommend the Task Parallel Library. In particular, the `Parallel` type. PLINQ is sometimes easier to use but it will assume that it can use all cores by default; since you're doing a Win32 service you'd want to be a bit "nicer" (to use Linux terminology).

TPL Dataflow is a great library that takes `async`/`await` to the next level. It does sound like your solution could use a TPL Dataflow-based approach. You can also "mix and match" between `async`, TPL, and TPL Dataflow quite nicely.